# Mount folder as drive

Tags: mount, udev

I'm using a `udev` rule on Ubuntu Xenial to automate some disc processing. Now I have a bunch of folders containing the plain files of optical discs, so there is no `.iso` available. To prevent expensive extending of processing script to handle these plain folders, I thought the best idea would be to simulate a disc with file system type `udf`. Is there a way to mount these folders like an optical drive to let `udev` handle the rest (so that `udevadm info` returns meta data like for a real optical device)?

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'expensive extending'. If you mean coding to handle folders - how about using an existing program to create .iso (in iso9660 or udf format) file and then mounting that. If you mean 'repackaging as an .iso file' - please ignore this comment :)

Comment: Are you talking about something like `cdemu` (http://cdemu.sourceforge.net/) ? Though I don't know if/how it lets you link in a plain directory tree

Comment: What do you mean by “mount folders like an optical drive”? Mounting makes a disk or disk image appear as a directory. So masquerading a directory as a disk image to make it appear as a directory achieves… what? Why don't you point your scripts to this directory? Udev is only involved to handle hardware, not to do any mounting, it's irrelevant to disk images. [What are you actually trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You all pointed me in the right direction. What I want is to emulate an optical drive that behaves like a real drive. But the challenge is to not use an `.iso` but an existing folder instead. @RalphRönnquist I'll give this a try and give feedback (could take a while) @Gilles The script I'm using expects a real drive in `/dev/srX` so pointing to directory does not work (have already tried this).